# Why does a cascode remove the Cgd effect?

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

If you add a cascode like in the image in a common source amplifier with diode-connected load, why is the effect of the Cgd capacitance of the M1 transistor removed? I don't understand it.

[image: CS Cascode amplifier]

Comment: What is the AC voltage at the drain of M1 and why is that so (go back to the basics of the individual impedances of the source & drain terminals)? That will lead you to the answer.

Comment: Read up on Miller effect: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_effect).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The action is pretty much as described by Andy aka. However, how well it works is affected by the gm of the various devices.

If Mb is not present so the design is a simple common drain amplifier  with a diode connected PFET as a load (M1 and M2), the gain from Vin to Vout will be just unity if the If the gm of M1 and M2 are the same. The effective load impedance of M1 is 1/gm(M2) so the gain is just gm(M1/gm(M2).

Therefore at Vin the effective input capacitance 2 * Cgd(M1). This is because any voltage change at Vin results in an equal and opposite voltage change at the drain of M1 resulting in twice the voltage change across the capacitor.

If Mb is added to make the circuit a cascade and Mb has the same gm as M1 and M2 the gain from Vin to M1 drain will be gm(M1) * 1/gm(Mb). This is also unity. So the effective input capacitance is again 2 * Cgd(M1).

If, for example, the gm of Mb is doubled relative to the other devices, the voltage change at the drain of M1 would be halved so the voltage change across Cgd(M1) would be reduced, reducing the effective input capacitance. The gm of the devices in an IC can be controlled by the device geometry.

Similarly if the gm of M2 is reduced, the voltage change at the drain of M1 would be less than the change at Vout and so the effective multiplication of Cgd is reduced.

One way to effectively reduce the gm of M2 is to make it a constant current rather than a diode connected PFET. With this approach the gain from Vin to Vout will be greatly increased but the gain the M1(drain) is not affected. In this case there can be a significant advantage to using the cascade.

Discrete implementations may use a resistor or tuned circuit as the load to give a high drain impedance for M2. The tuned circuit would be used in for example RF amplifiers where reducing the effect of Cgd not only reduces the load on the previous stage but also may be necessary to avoid oscillation.

The same circuit configuration is used with other types of device such as bipolar junction transistors or electron tubes for similar reasons. It has been used for more than 80 years.

[image: Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascode#/media/File:MOSFET_Cascode.png)]

[Wikipedia - Cascode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascode#/media/File:MOSFET_Cascode.png)

Answer (score 1):

Mb forces the drain of M1 to a near constant DC voltage hence, the capacitance from M1's drain to either its source or gate is not subject to much of a voltage change and, M1's speed (or bandwidth) is significantly improved. M1's current injection into the source of Mb is the main aim here and, that is achieved with minimal voltage fluctuation on its drain (thanks to Mb acting almost like a voltage regulator at its own source.

Comment: If the gm of MB and M2 are the same then the voltage changes at M1 drain will be the same as MB (&M2) drain so the cascade will give no advantage. If however MB has higher gm than M2 then there will be an advantage as the voltage changes and feedback will be less.

Comment: Maybe you should justify that and make an answer. Personally I'm not seeing it but I'm quite happy to be revitalized by this @Kevin